# Upgrading to Ubuntu Mate 20.04

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, mate

I am or was on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Saw a prompt for a large upgrade thru Software & Updates so I clicked ok and let it run

After booting I saw the grub screen as normal then just a black screen
Was able to launch a terminal and ran sudo apt-get update etc and after some tweaks was able to get sort of a desktop environment(see attached)

However obviously not what I need. Screen resolution is wrong, not getting proper mouse tracking, etc.
Checking in terminal I confirm that I am now on 20.04LTS.
I also downloaded the Ubuntu MATE .iso file

How do I properly upgrade my MATE skin to 20.04?

In hindsight I should have followed these directions

https://www.fosslinux.com/38695/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-mate-18-04-or-19-10-to-20-04-lts.htm

Any feedback appreciated.[image]

Comment: It is hard to say what gone wrong during upgrade. Video resolution may degrade because of missed video driver. What is your current video card? Do you have any errors when you run `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` ?